# How to summon an item frame facing a specific direction in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working on a map and I need to summon an item frame in a specific place. I'm using the command:

`/summon item_frame -1242 58 219`

but "it is **on the ground**" and I need it to face north.

Answer (score 2):

You need to summon the entity with custom NBT: `/summon minecraft:item_frame -1242 58 219 {Facing:2}`

The `Facing` part is what is added. The default number is 1, which is facing up. 2 is facing north, which you are looking for. If you try different numbers, you will find that it will face different directions.